# vue-cli: proxy a full url to development server

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-cli

I'm building an app with `vue`. For a long time I've always used the `devServer` property through the `vue-cli` to handle my `api` requests. This always looked something like:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost/my-project-api',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
                "^/api": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then my `axios` request would look like:

```
axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "/api/endpoint/",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    responseType: "json"
})
.then((response) => {
    resolve(response.data);
})
.catch((error) => {
    reject(error);
});
```

This always works fine, since on production my `api` folder is on the same server.

For a new project I'm hosting my `api` on a seperate server (subdomain) like `https://api.mydomain.com` while my project runs on the subdomain `https://project.mydomain.com`.

How do I arange this in my proxy? I tried this:

```
proxy: {
    'https://api.mydomain.com': {
        target: 'http://localhost/my-project-api',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            "https://api.mydomain.com": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Then my back-end request through `axios` looks like:

```
axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://api.mydomain.com/endpoint/",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    responseType: "json"
})
.then((response) => {
    resolve(response.data);
})
.catch((error) => {
    reject(error);
});
```

But tyhen I get a `cors` complaint which tells me the proxy isn't using my dev server.

Any experience ont this?